# How to have a external config file in react app with vite bundler

Tags: reactjs, configuration, vite, vitest

I am learning React and don't know the correct way to create config files. I want to have an external configuration file in my React-based project with Vite bundler. As I want to change the configurations according to my wish while using the app and the configuration file should not bundle with my app.

I have created a config.js file in a public folder that didn't work.